# Lemo connector parts for Sennheiser SK5212 body pack transmitter

Tags: sennheiser

I apologize if this question is off topic.

I regularly repair DPA lav mics used for broadcast purposes.  The failure is almost always that the mic cable shield has disintegrated right at the Lemo connector.  I am able to reuse almost all of the original connector except for the ferrule that actually grips the cable.  The connector body, pins, retaining ring, strain-relief boot are all okay and can be reused.

I would like to find out the Lemo part number for that ferrule.

A replacement Lemo connector from Sennheiser is part number 049916 and sells for about US $50.

I have another 24 lav mics that need to be repaired, along with enough Lemo parts to make another 25 or 30 connectors.

The actual failure mode is that the users are extremely careless when taking the body pack off and just "rip" the pack free from their body.  The shield just is not sufficiently robust and it eventually disintegrates. I often have to trim the lav cable by several inches until I find where the shield is intact.  Surprisingly, the center conductor never seems to fail.

Guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the lemo website says ? https://www.lemo.com/int_en/productfinder or your local dealer ?

Comment: Your link is helpful.  What I downloaded previously does not dive into individual component pieces of the connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time with Google and with the help of an eBay seller, I have some part numbers.  This may help others in the same situation I am in.

entire connector: FVB.00.303.NLAE2

crimp part only: FVG.00.160.DN

Both Mouser and Digikey have the crimp part available and in stock.